# Checkbox in post not saving value

Tags: metabox

I have a checkbox above my metabox in a custom post. When I check it and publish/update the post, it become unchecked again meaning it's not saving it's value. Here is my code for the checkbox:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_box'); 
add_action('save_post', 'save_postdata');   
function my_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'movie_meta_box',
        'Movie Meta Options',
        'movie_options_meta_box_func',
        'movie'
    );
}
function movie_options_meta_box_func( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'movie_noncename' );
  $mydata = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'movie', TRUE);
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="movie_abc" name="movie_abc" value="true" />';
  echo '<input type="text" id="movie_xyz" name="movie_xyz" value="'.$mydata['movie_xyz'].'" size="60" />';
}
function save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
      return;
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
      return;
  $mydata = array();
  foreach($_POST as $key => $data) {
    if($key == 'movie_noncename')
      continue;
    if(preg_match('/^/i', $key)) 
    {
      $mydata[$key] = $data;
    }
  }
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'movie', $mydata);
  return $mydata;
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change,

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="movie_abc" name="movie_abc" value="true" />';
```

to...

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="movie_abc" name="movie_abc" value="1"' . checked( $mydata , 1 ) . '/>';
```

...and let us know how you go.

#### Update

Try the following,

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="movie_abc" name="movie_abc" value="1"', $mydata ? ' checked="checked"' : '', '/>';
```

#### Update 2

This is a duplicate question;

I now see in your code that you are not updating the meta_key values for,

```
movie_abc and movie_xyz
```

So you need to add,

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'movie_abc', $mydata); //current value of this key is "true" only?
update_post_meta($post_id, 'movie_xyz', $mydata);
```

...to your `save_postdata()` function.

#### Update 3

```
$mydata = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'movie', TRUE);
if($mydata  == true)
$checked  = 'checked="checked"'; 
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="movie_abc" name="movie_abc" value=""', $checked, '/>';
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have implemented it but it's not working.

Comment: What happens if you change,  `checked( $mydata , 1 )` to `(checked( $mydata , 1 ))` - add extra brackets around side or alternatively `checked( $mydata , 1, false )`

Comment: I have tried both with both- that is- with parentheses and with false, but it didn't work.

Comment: About saving of meta key value: Actually if you see I'm not saving meta key value for text input but I manage to save its value so I think that's not the matter.

Comment: What is the point of `movie_abc` - I don't follow your logic, it doesn't appear to be passed into your function, and the point of your regex?

Comment: I'm just only confused about why my checkbox not saving value where as the text field is saving value with the same function. That's what I'm looking for.